# What are the practices and beliefs of Islam regarding death?

Tags: death

I am writing a paper for a nursing assistant course. The subject is death and the beliefs and practices of different cultures and religions regarding death and dying. Would you please explain to me what your beliefs are regarding death and what you do when someone dies? Just keep in mind that I am not a Muslim myself and would prefer not to have to look up a lot of words. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome on Islam stack exchange the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about this site and the stack exchange model I strongly recommend you to take our [tour] and check the [help]. As is your question seems to me a bit too broad. Would it be possible to focus it or clearly point at what you'd like to know? I guess the first which would come to mind are the funeral rituals, but as it is a nursing course you might also be more interested in topics such how to treat the death body, or what to do if you think a patient might die (spiritual guidance)...